autocomplete attribute for city / state / zip?
According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete street-address "should not include the city name, ZIP or postal code, or country name".
So if the city / state / zip aren't included then how does one enable auto completion on them?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete says, of address-level2, that "this would typically be the city, town, village, or other locality in which the address is located", however, it also says address-level2 "should only be present if the "street-address" is not present".


...address-level2 "should only be present if the "street-address" is not present".

I believe this may have been an understandable misreading (or the MDN documents made a typo and corrected it), as it specifies address-line should not be present with street-address, rather than address-level.
address-line1, address-line2, address-line3 are for individual lines of the street address (which makes them redundant when combined with street-address), while address-level1/address-level2/etc are for administrative levels, which is what you're looking for here.
This can be seen more clearly at: html.spec.whatwg.org on autocomplete.
As an example, if you are working with US-based addresses, the city would be handled by address-level2, the state by address-level1, and the zip code by postal-code.
